# Drawing a "smooth" 90° arrow with TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows

How can I draw arrows like these with TikZ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You should provide what you try so far!
- From Image can be concluded that you like to draw arrows with rounded corners:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
arr/.style = {draw=#1, rounded corners=3mm, semithick, -Straight Barb}
                        ]
\draw[arr=red]  (0,0) -- ++ (0,-1) -|  (-2,-2); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! thank you. Sorry for not sharing any MWE, I just didn't know how to do it simply, I had nothing but a "normal" arrow with sharp corners, nothing interesting. Thanks again